# IBM PS/2 Model 56 486 SLC2 Faceplate replacement

Tags: ibm, case

I'm trying to track down a replacement faceplate for an IBM PS/2 Model 56. Mine was broken during shipping. Anybody have any ideas where I could find one?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to find another piece on eBay. You can set the "search watch" and then you will get a message when someone adds a suitable item. Sometimes you can find just "case" or "plastic". But be patient.